# How do I generate a logarithmic x-axis without a y-axis?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to plot the following image using TikZ:

[image]

How do I generate an X-axis with logarithmic scaling using TikZ? For linear scaling I use this code:

```
\usetikzlibrary{plotmarks}
%axis
\draw (3,0) -- coordinate (x axis mid) (21,0);

    %ticks
    \foreach \x in {3,...,21}
        \draw (\x,0pt) -- (\x,-3pt)
        node[anchor=north] {\x};

%labels      
\node[below=0.8cm] at (x axis mid) {Physical dose [Gy]};
```

Comment: Maybe it could be faster to use `pgfplots`

Comment: Yes, but I don't know how to remove the y-axis in pgfplots.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This looks like a job for PGFPlots:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    y=1.5cm,            % y unit vector
    hide y axis,        % hide the y axis
    xmode = log,        % logarithmic x axis
    axis x line*=bottom,% only show the bottom x axis line, without an arrow tip
    xmin=1e-4, xmax=1e2,% range for the x axis
    xlabel = Dose in Sv
]
\addplot [no markers, line width=6pt] table {
0.002 1
0.004 1
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You may also skip the repeaded 1's and use an `y expr=1` insted.

Answer (score 4):

It is not supposed to be the correct way to go. Feel free to edit!

[image]

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\def\f[#1,#2]{!#1 log 4 add #2 8 div}
\begin{document}
\pspicture(0,-0.25)(6,0.125)
    \psaxes
        [
            yAxis=false,
            subticks=9,
            xlogBase=10,
            Ox=-4,
            logLines=x,
            ticksize=-1.5pt 1.5pt,
        ](6,0.125)
    \psline[linewidth=2\pslinewidth](\f[0.002,1])(\f[0.004,1])
\endpspicture
\end{document}
```