# Log scale, ticks scaling and natural numbers

Tags: scaling, ticks

I want to reproduce this logaritmic scale with this kind of scaling and these ticks, how can I do?

[image]

Here it is the code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{semilogxaxis}[xmin=1,xmax=7,ymin=0,ymax=1000,
                                 xlabel=$E_\textup{vis}^\textup{obs}$ (MeV),
                                 ylabel=$\frac{dN}{dE_\textup{vis}^\textup{obs}}$, ylabel style={rotate=-90},
                                 width=12cm, height=8cm,
                                 legend style={draw=none},
                                 log ticks with fixed point]

                \addplot [thick,blue]
                file {data/curveIdealNH.txt};
                \addplot [thick,red]
            \end{semilogxaxis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
```

The datafile is not important, you can plot anything.
Thanks so much.

Comment: Are you plotting anything or you want just the axis?

Comment: I'm plotting from a file, I can post the code if necessary but it's trivial

Comment: If you post the minimal code with sample data, it will be useful for us.

Comment: Possibly related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/98695/how-do-i-generate-a-logarithmic-x-axis-without-a-y-axis

Comment: I don't quite understand the question, what is it you want to produce? The code in your question appears to be fully functional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some thing like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{semilogxaxis}[xmin=1,xmax=10,ymin=0,ymax=1000,
                                 xlabel=$E_\textup{vis}^\textup{obs}$ (MeV),
                                 ylabel=$\frac{dN}{dE_\textup{vis}^\textup{obs}}$,
                                 xtick=\empty,
                                 extra x ticks={2,...,10},
                                 extra x tick labels={2,...,10},
                                 ylabel style={rotate=-90},
                                 width=12cm, height=8cm,
                                 legend style={draw=none},
                                 log ticks with fixed point]

                \addplot [thick,blue] {rnd};
            \end{semilogxaxis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I have removed `xtick`s and used `extra x ticks` and labelled them.